# Is it possible to configure ASDoc to check spelling in comments?

Tags: actionscript-3, spelling, asdoc

Is there a way (configuration) to generate ASDoc which will highlight misspelled words or create error feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - it is not possible. That's completely out of the scope ASDoc is implemented for.